# Receiving error message upon attemtped form submisison. PHP Mailer

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I have a form on my site that was working fine up until today. Now whenever I try and send a message I am met with the following error message:

```
Notice:  fputs() [function.fputs]: send of 29 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/lib/class.smtp.php on line 653

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.' in /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/lib/class.phpmailer.php:1076
Stack trace:
#0 /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/lib/class.phpmailer.php(971): PHPMailer->SmtpConnect()
#1 /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/lib/class.phpmailer.php(845): PHPMailer->SmtpSend('Date: Wed, 25 J...', '--b1_85ace9c961...')
#2 /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/lib/class.phpmailer.php(763): PHPMailer->PostSend()
#3 /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/process.php(390): PHPMailer->Send()
#4 /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/process.php(444): process(Object(Quform), Array)
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/m29darr/public_html/quform/lib/class.phpmailer.php on line 1076
```

I am testing my website before it is launched but upon trying to send an email on the form I am met with this message? I have no idea how to fix it. I have re-uploaded the original file thinking that perhaps the old one on the server had somehow become corrupt but that did nothing!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: the important line is "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host" are you using the right smtp sever? that you have access to ?

Comment: Check your SMTP credentials, maybe the password changed since it stopped working.

Comment: Where did you download Phpmailer, what kind of server do you use (e.g. IIS, Apache, Nginx) and can you please show your form and post codes to us?

Comment: From the cPanel of my host? I will take a look now. I am not cluded up at all on anything php or phpmailer so am lost here...

Comment: the form has nothing to do with the error

Comment: @Dagon ok so it maybe a password thing though? I have just installed a blog yesterday and it has phpmailer as well. so effectively I have 2 phpmailers both connecting to SMTP. If I changed the password when I installed the blog could this be where the problem is?

Comment: if the password changed was the mail server password - then yes, obvious, that could be the problem, but i don't see a blog installation doing that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It was the password! I have no idea how I changed it? I certainly do not remember doing so but hey I changed it back to the same as it is within the process.php file and sent myself a message with success! I will keep the error message in case this happens again as I now know how to resolve it. I had no idea at all so thank you all so much for pointing me in the right direction.